# How to make MGT React People Picker component required

Tags: microsoft-graph-toolkit

How do I make the people picker component from MGT required?

I am currently using formik to validate the form

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't currently a feature available to support form validation with the MGT people-picker. Also, the input is most likely hidden in the shadow dom behind the control.

Instead... I'd recommend you open a "[feature request](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/issues/new/choose)" on the mgt repository, with the details necessary for your request, and we'll triage and handle the issue as we have availability.

Comment: Created - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/issues/1261